# Confusion on printing boolean literals in python

Tags: python

In python shell mode, I tried using the command print(true) which I knew would not work because of absence of quotes and so showed a error, but when I used print(True) it displayed True on the screen. Can anyone please explain to me what is going on as I am just a beginner to python.

Edit: I searched for different keywords and tried them with print() but all words like and,as,assert,break showed a syntax error but only None worked and printed
Can someone please explain this.
[image: 1]]

Comment: It is impossible in python if you are writing print(Null) and getting the output. Except True and False, you cant use any keyword in print() which can be directly printed.

Comment: Sorry I meant None instead of Null (None is used to represent a Null value)

Answer (score 3):

It is happening because `True` is a reserved keyword.

It doesn't require quotes while `true` is just like a random string for the compiler.

That is why print(True) is giving you output as `True`

print(true) gives the output as this  `NameError: name 'true' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

True is a reserved keyword. It is the Boolean value True and is opposite False. Lowercase true is not a reserved keyword and will cause an error because it appears to python as an undeclared variable

Answer (score 0):

All keywords in Python are lower in case except True and False. That's why print(true) doesn't work and print(True) works.

Answer (score 0):

In python, `True` is a keyword. This means when you try to execute printing `True` the python understands the user is telling me to print the boolean value `True`. But when you try to print `true` at that time python understands, ok the user is telling me to print a string `true` and it found out that as it is a string so you forgot to give `'` at the first and last of the string. That's why it is giving syntax errors.

So the theory is `True` is a python boolean value and a keyword and `true` is a simple string

Answer (score 0):

Python has a set of keywords that are reserved words that cannot be used as variable names, function names, or any other identifiers.

Some examples are:

```
if
else
for
while
and
etc...
```

Boolean values fall into this category. In Python, boolean values are capitalized. When you run `print(True)`, python recognizes `True` as a keyword and prints the boolean value it represents.

When you run `print(true)` python doesn't match it to any reserved keywords and assumes it be a variable. However, in this case true has not be previously defined or assigned a value. Since Python doesn't know what `true` means it throws an error